# Images is not showing after migration

Tags: plugins, themes

I have a link in which i am showing images.

But the image exist in the directory, when i visit direct image it is showing 404

**http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/9780007322602-100x128.jpg**

But i doubled checked image is sitting into upload folder

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that the image `9780007322602-100x128.jpg` exists under `wp-content/uploads/2015/04/9780007322602-100x128.jpg` but he URL `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/9780007322602-100x128.jpg` return 404 error?

Comment: Try editing the file permissions to 777 and check. Reset it to 755 after finding the problem.